# Rust CXX & CMake FFI bindings for C++ library to be used in rust code

Tags: c++, rust, cmake, rust-cargo, ffi

I have the following error during `cargo build` of a project using [`cxx`](https://cxx.rs/) with [`cmake`](https://docs.rs/cmake/latest/cmake/index.html) for compiling a C++ library to be callable in rust.

Here is the error from `cargo build`:

```
ld: warning: object file (/usr/local/lib/libwhisper.a(ggml.c.o)) was built for newer macOS version (12.6) than being linked (12.0)
ld: warning: object file (/usr/local/lib/libwhisper.a(whisper.cpp.o)) was built for newer macOS version (12.6) than being linked (12.0)
  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_cxxbridge1$whisper_init", referenced from:
      whisper_rust::interop::ffi::whisper_init::hbcdc3c0c1120a6a9 in whisper_rust-2cf5d7323dfcdb42.1p80ceksqm40omuj.rcgu.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is my code in `interop.rs` using `cxx::bridge` macro:

```rust
#[cxx::bridge]
pub mod ffi {
    unsafe extern "C++" {
        type whisper_token;
        type whisper_context;

        fn whisper_init(path_model: &CxxString) -> *mut whisper_context; // this line causes the error
    }
}
```

the last function declaration is the faulty one, commenting out the line make me build the project successfully but without interacting with the static C++ library this is useless.
That refers to a function decl. in the header:

```
struct whisper_context * whisper_init(const char * path_model);
```

Here's my `build.rs`:

```rust
println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/whisper-cpp/*");
    
let dst = cmake::build("src/whisper-cpp");
println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", dst.display());
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=whisper");
```

And this is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```bash
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.9" CACHE STRING "Minimum OS X deployment version")
project(whisper VERSION 0.1.0)

# add compiler flags
set(CMAKE_CC_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CC_FLAGS} -I. -O3 -pthread")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I. -O3 -std=c++11 -pthread")


# platform-dependent compiler flags
...

# add source files
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)

# add library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${SRC_LIST})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "whisper.h")

# install
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include)
```

I'm not sure where my problem lies, I guess this is related the compilation step of CMakeLists but can be also generated by a bad build.rs setup.
I've already tried without success:

- rebuilding / clean cache and then rebuilt
- including the header file in `interop.rs`
- looking for answers here, google, reddit, etc. for hours
- changing the version of OSX required by cmake (this still doesn't make any difference shown in the error, makes me wonder...)

I spent way too hours doing this, I'm still learning FFI and I'll be very thankful if you can help me get out of this mess. Thank you.

**EDIT**: I updated the system, reinstalled cmake and set file in place of include in build.rs, this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`cxx` will generate cpp code for your `interop.rs` in `target/cxxbridge` but it seems that you didn't include it in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

For example,

```
set(CXXBRIDGE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/target/cxxbridge)
add_library(whisper SHARED your_cpp_file.cc ${CXXBRIDGE}/your_project_name/src/bridge.rs.cc)
```